# react-redux: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to use redux on my react project and I have an issue when the "connect()" method from "react-redux" is used.

I create the store and the reducer I need but when I try to connect my component, nothing displays and it gives me the error.

When I try to connect my component App:

```
import React from "react";
import PrivateRoute from "react-private-route";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

import indexRoutes from "routes/index";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
      return (<Router>[...]</Router>);
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    myInfo: state
  };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    test: () => dispatch({ type: "TEST", payload: {} })
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

I get the error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Please include the `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and `App` in your question as well or it will be very hard for someone to figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's edited now.

Comment: Is `[...]` in render a placeholder for something?

Comment: It's to hide unnacessary code.

Comment: could you please include the imports as well? Sounds like you're not importing something properly

Comment: Done. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What line is that error originating from? Code you have posted looks ok

Comment: I'm guessing this is your main entry component? If so consider wrapping it in `<Provider>` and `<ConnectedRouter>` instead of `<Router>`. You have a working example here https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router#step-3

Comment: Thank you for the link !!
I works !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment the solution is to wrap your app in `<Provider></Provider>`, which makes the store available to nested components that use `connect()`. If you are using react router v4 you should also use `<ConnectedRouter>` instead of the simple router.

A good working example can be found in [their Github docs](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router#step-3)

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}> { }
        ...
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```